# Retrieving name of the module from which the function is called in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I want to display the module name from which the function is called in codeigniter. Consider for example if there are 2 modules, abc and xyz. Both have controllers abc and xyz, whose snippet is similar to this:

```
class Abc{
 function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
 }}
```

And

```
class Xyz{
  function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
  }
  function index() {
    $this->load->module('abc');
    echo $this->router->fetch_module();
  }
 }
```

Now when I call index function of module xyz, I get the output as 'abc' where I want the name of the module in which the function is present should be displayed i.e xyz. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? I haven't used CodeIgniter HMVC before so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

```
class Abc{
 protected $rootModuleName;

 function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
 }

 function setRootModuleName($name) {
    $this->rootModuleName = $name;
 }
}

class Xyz{
  function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
  }
  function index() {
    $this->load->module('abc');
    $this->abc->setRootModuleName(__CLASS__); //or you could just pass the string 'Xyz'

    //This call would need to somehow make use of the $rootModuleName property
    echo $this->router->fetch_module();
  }
 }
```

Comment: It can be a fallback. Not a complete solution.

Comment: FYI, you may already be aware of this, but in terms of PHP itself the only way to detect where a function call originated would be to use `debug_backtrace()`, which should be avoided for non-debugging purposes. Not sure if that's relevant here, just thought I'd mention it.